# Spring Boot @Query Annotation countQuery works but countName not

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to execute some native queries using the `@Query` annotation with Spring and I'm having the follow problem:

I have a file called: `jpa-named-queries.properties` where I put my queries and I have one query to get the data and one query to count the data.
Ej:

```
Find.members.team = SELECT ct.id teamId, r.user_id userId, (SELECT SUM(rd.resume_value) FROM resume_detail rd WHERE rd.resume_id = r.id) resumeMemberValue FROM resume r INNER JOIN challenge_team ct ON r.team_id = ct.id WHERE ct.id = :teamId ORDER BY resumeMemberValue ASC
Find.members.team.count = SELECT count(resume.id) FROM resume INNER JOIN challenge_team ct ON resume.team_id = ct.id WHERE ct.id = :teamId
```

and I have the Repository method to use the queries:

```
@Query(name = "Find.members.team", 
       countName= "Find.members.team.count",  
       nativeQuery = true)
Page<TeamMemberProjection> findMembersTeamByIdWithPagination(@Param("teamId") Long id, Pageable pageable);
```

The problem is If I execute as shown above the queries execute are:

```
Hibernate: SELECT ct.id teamId, r.user_id userId, (SELECT SUM(rd.resume_value) FROM resume_detail rd WHERE rd.resume_id = r.id) resumeMemberValue FROM resume r INNER JOIN challenge_team ct ON r.team_id = ct.id WHERE ct.id = ? ORDER BY resumeMemberValue ASC limit ?
Hibernate: select count(rd) FROM resume_detail rd WHERE rd.resume_id = r.id) resumeMemberValue FROM resume r INNER JOIN challenge_team ct ON r.team_id = ct.id WHERE ct.id = ?
```

And thats cause a exception because the query executed makes no sense.

But if I use the **countQuery** property of the annotation like:

```
@Query(name = "Find.members.team", 
       countQuery= "SELECT count(resume.id) FROM resume INNER JOIN challenge_team ct ON resume.team_id = ct.id WHERE ct.id = :teamId",  
       nativeQuery = true)
Page<TeamMemberProjection> findMembersTeamByIdWithPagination(@Param("teamId") Long id, Pageable pageable);

The queries executed are:
Hibernate: SELECT ct.id teamId, r.user_id userId, (SELECT SUM(rd.resume_value) FROM resume_detail rd WHERE rd.resume_id = r.id) resumeMemberValue FROM resume r INNER JOIN challenge_team ct ON r.team_id = ct.id WHERE ct.id = ? ORDER BY resumeMemberValue ASC limit ?
Hibernate: SELECT count(resume.id) FROM resume INNER JOIN challenge_team ct ON resume.team_id = ct.id WHERE ct.id = ?
```

And that works perfectly.

The documentation of these properties tells:
**countName**

```
Returns the name of the javax.persistence.NamedQuery to be used to execute count queries when pagination is used. Will default to the named query name configured suffixed by .count.
```

**countQuery**

```
Returns the name of the javax.persistence.NamedQuery to be used to execute count queries when pagination is used. Will default to the named query name configured suffixed by .count.
```

I have used these two properties together in others examples and works perfectly but in this special case I don't understand what mistake I'm doing.